# Popping/Buzzing sound when pluging in speakers with external power

Tags: audio, hardware-failure, speakers, headphone-jack

I have these speakers (Genius SP-HF1250B) with power drawn from power socket and every time I am plugging them in, from the point when connector touches the jack input connector to the point of full insertion, it buzzes/pops very loud (same if I touch end of cable with finger). Could this damage those speakers and more importantly could this damage the PC?

If so, what would you suggest to prevent this from happening? If I turn off speakers by switch on the back of them before inserting and turn them back on after, the sound is obviously not there, but I am worried that some power "surge" is still there and could damage PC/speakers.

Also I plug it in/out every day because as far as I know there is no way to have connected headphones and speakers so they would both play (or alternatively ito have possibility to choose - for me always front jack plays if both inserted) at the same time right?

Thanks for any suggestions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior. When you turn on the speaker, it will amplify electric signals that come through the jack, an "armed" speaker will therefor cause these sounds to be played on the speaker because the plus and minus on the cable will cause for imbalances.

> from the point when connector touches the jack input connector to the point of full insertion, it buzzes/pops very loud (same if I touch end of cable with finger). Could this damage those speakers and more importantly could this damage the PC?

Yes, if you have the speaker turned on, it is possible to damage the speaker or the soundcard. It is unlikely but it can happen. This is basically true for any audio equipment.

> If so, what would you suggest to prevent this from happening? If I turn off speakers by switch on the back of them before inserting and turn them back on after, the sound is obviously not there, but I am worried that some power "surge" is still there and could damage PC/speakers.

Exactly this. You turn off the speaker, then plug it in, then turn it on. That is the safe method to do it and that should not yield in any damage. If that does yield in damage, then you have a really cheap speaker that will break no matter what. No, a speaker and soundcard will normally withstand that.

> Also I plug it in/out every day because as far as I know there is no way to have connected headphones and speakers so they would both play (or alternatively ito have possibility to choose - for me always front jack plays if both inserted) at the same time right?

That's fine. Note that the front jack with the headphones are not amplified and can be removed and inserted safely. But if it is that same jack you plug in the speakers too, then yes, the speakers need to be turned off. Usually there is also a jack on the back of your pc (laptops excluded, they only have one), and if you plug the speakers in the back, and the headphones in the front, on most systems the speakers are automatically muted.